# Vimeo Advanced API 3 - Search Private Videos?

Tags: ajax, search, video, vimeo-api

I am trying to build an autocomplete that returns my video titles and their VideoID from the advanced vimeo API v3 (authenticated with OAUTH).  My videos are not marked public yet.  I cannot seem to get any results back from the search method unless the videos are made public. I have tried this in the sandbox and in production.

Any ideas on how I can get access to my videos based on query keywords using search, or at some point tags?  I am not able to publish my videos for public consumption yet and need to build out a tool to allow my back office folks to search for and manage the videos while they are private...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimeo's search functionality does not support private videos. This matches the search found on vimeo.com.

The best way to handle this is to index the data locally (using your own search service) and call to  vimeo when you need embed information.